# Type '{ root: { closeButton: { margin: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IStyleFunctionOrObject<IPanelStyleProps, IPanelStyles>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
                    <Panel
                        isOpen={this.state.showPanel}
                        onDismiss={this.onPanelClose}
                        type={PanelType.medium}
                        hasCloseButton={true}
                        closeButtonAriaLabel="Close Submission Details"
                        headerText={escape(strings.ListSubmissionsStatusPanelHeader)}
                        isFooterAtBottom={true}
                        onRenderFooterContent={this.renderFooter}
                        styles={{root: {closeButton: {margin: '2px'} }}}
                    >
```

On running this, I see:

> error TS2322: Type '{ root: { closeButton: { margin: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IStyleFunctionOrObject<IPanelStyleProps, IPanelStyles>'

How do I fix this?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: office-ui-fabric-react

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but it looks like [this documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling#componentts) might be useful to you